# How to remove double quotes from dynamic url genereted from the select options In Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am want to create the url, which will fetch the json data from the server. I am able to generate the dynamic url but it contains the **double quotes**
`http://localhost/admin/metering/samples?meter="instance"&group_by="project"&stats_attr="avg"&date_options=7&date_from=&date_to=`

Please see above url it contains the **"instance"** in double quotes, But it should be not like that,
**correct url is** `http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering/samples?meter=instance&group_by=project&stats_attr=avg&date_options=7&date_from=&date_to=`

**Note**: If you know good ways to generate the dynamic url then you can tell me.

**Working Demo** http://plnkr.co/edit/Ygkqlf60SLaLTtBaUoJf?p=preview

**Angularjs**

```
 $http.get("data.json")
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.metrics = response.nova_meters.concat(response.glance_meters);

      $scope.metric = $scope.metrics[0];         
       $scope.groups=[{"name": "project", "value":"project" ,"label": "project"}];
      $scope.group_by = $scope.groups[0];  
       $scope.stats_attrs=[
      {
            "name": "avg", 
            "value": "avg",         
            "label": "avg"            
      },
      {
            "name": "min",
            "value": "min",          
            "label": "min"            
      },
      {
            "name": "max", 
            "value": "max",         
            "label": "max"            
      },
      {
            "name": "sum", 
            "value": "sum",         
            "label": "sum"            
      }
   ];

      $scope.stats_attr = $scope.stats_attrs[0];         
      $scope.date_options = [{
        "value": 1,
        "label": "Last day"
      }, {
        "value": 7,
        "label": "Last week"
      }, {
        "value": 23,
        "label": "Month to date"
      }, {
        "value": 30,
        "label": "Last 30 days"
      }, {
        "value": 356,
        "label": "Last year"
      }, {
        "value": "Other",
        "label": "Other"
      }];

      $scope.date_option = $scope.date_options[1];          
      var url="http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering/samples?"+"meter="+JSON.stringify($scope.metric.label)+"&group_by="+JSON.stringify($scope.group_by.label)+"&stats_attr="+JSON.stringify($scope.stats_attr.label)+"&date_options="+JSON.stringify($scope.date_option.value)+"&date_from=&date_to=";

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove JSON.stringify from the url

```
var url="http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering/samples?"+"meter="+$scope.metric.label+"&group_by="+$scope.group_by.label+"&stats_attr="+$scope.stats_attr.label+"&date_options="+$scope.date_option.value+"&date_from=&date_to=";
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/uvqwbBttzPRXgIQLOEOL?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify()` is adding those quotes. In your case, you dont really need it.

> JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

So, just remove `JSON.stringify()` from your code and it will work as expected.

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BG9E30aUv9R81S3SNgsU?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the JSON.stringify from your URL generation and it will work as expected:

```
var url="http://192.168.206.133:8080/admin/metering/samples?meter="+$scope.metric.label+"&group_by="+$scope.group_by.label+"&stats_attr="+$scope.stats_attr.label+"&date_options="+$scope.date_option.value+"&date_from=&date_to=";
```